# How can I use C# to write and play music?

Tags: c#, .net

So, long story short, I am laying down the framework to create an evolutionary algorithm that will write music and export it to a file for me to listen to.

My question is, are there any programs out there that I can interface with, so that I can just feed the software notes and it builds the piece?

If not, how do I do this myself?

Answer (score 9):

I wonder what kind of answers you expect, considering the scope of relevant topics. I'd just bring [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) to the table which may help you in your undertaking.

Since it also knows MIDI, maybe you have a Midi device (your soundcard?) Then you can create MIDI events and send them to your device. The result could be music.

Answer (score 6):

You could use parts of the [C# Synth Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/synthtoolkitparti.aspx) for Sound creation. There are several parameters beyond freuency and time to play with. If you need, it speaks midi too eg. it can be connected with your (midi/usb-midi)-keyboard to play some notes of riffs.

For the (evolutionary) parameter generation you need a way for your algorithm to "measure" the quality of the generated output. There are some metrics in classical music theory but don't remember them.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [the C# MIDI Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx) allows you to write MIDI files: "The Sequence class represents a collection of Tracks. It also provides functionality for loading and saving MIDI files, so Sequences can load and save themselves." So assuming you can build a Sequence in code, that should allow you to get started pretty easily.

I looked at doing something similar in Java a while back and MIDI is a very easy format to use for this type of thing. And because it's so basic, almost all music-related programs will import it, meaning you could probably do things like turn it in to sheet music easily.

Answer (score 1):

**Music XML**

*Link:* http://www.musicxml.com/

There is endless documentation for Music XML. You can see a list of programs that can read and write Music XML at http://www.musicxml.com/software/.

So, you just need to create a class that has the attributes that you want to serialize. You will need to be familiar with [XML Serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part). Here is a rough example of how the classes will look:

```
[XmlRoot("score-partwise")]
public class Score
{
    Identity identification;
    Credit credit;
    List<PartItem> partList;
    List<Measure> part;
}

public class Identity
{
    // Documentation for Identification elements as link 1 below
}

public class Credit
{
    // Documentation for Credit elements as link 2 below
}

public class PartItem
{
    // Documentation for Part-List elements as link 3 below
}

public class Measure
{
    // Documentation for Measure elements as link 4 below
}
```

**Links to specific documentation**

1. http://www.musicxml.com/UserManuals/MusicXML/MusicXML.htm#CT-MusicXML-identification.htm#kanchor2610
2. http://www.musicxml.com/UserManuals/MusicXML/MusicXML.htm#CT-MusicXML-credit.htm#kanchor2397
3. http://www.musicxml.com/UserManuals/MusicXML/MusicXML.htm#CT-MusicXML-part-list.htm#kanchor2838
4. http://www.musicxml.com/UserManuals/MusicXML/MusicXML.htm#EL-MusicXML-measure.htm

---

**Music XML Example**

It can be fairly simple to write. Here is an example of one measure:

```
<measure>
  <note>
    <pitch>
      <step>F</step>
      <octave>5</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>eighth</type>
    <stem>down</stem>
  </note>
  <note>
    <pitch>
      <step>F</step>
      <alter>1</alter>
      <octave>5</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>6</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>quarter</type>
    <dot/>
    <accidental>sharp</accidental>
    <stem>down</stem>
  </note>
  <note>
    <pitch>
      <step>A</step>
      <alter>1</alter>
      <octave>4</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>8</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>half</type>
    <accidental>sharp</accidental>
    <stem>up</stem>
  </note>
</measure>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[NFugue](https://github.com/mchudy/NFugue) is a music programming library. It is [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org)'s C# port. Not very complete, but basic features are there. It can read and play MIDI and MusicXML files, create custom music patterns and progressions, save MIDI files and so on. Currently, real-time MIDI signal parsing is not ported.